# Grub menu for Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10 not showing up when starting the PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have two drives: a 120GB SSD, and a 1TB HDD. I installed Windows 10 in my SSD and installed Ubuntu in my HDD by creating a 250GB partition. After installing Ubuntu, I thought, as happened in my laptop (Intel) which I dual-booted, that it will show a grub menu. But it didn't. After researching a little bit I thought that my boot priority must be messed up.

But when I opened up my BIOS (Ryzen 5 1600, MSI B350) I saw something I never saw before - a visual BIOS. After sometime, I learned that I have to change the order of drive icons to change boot priority. But I have no idea what the order should be. There is nowhere written on the internet. I saw the first one is 'Windows boot loader'. Then a series of UEFI something, then normal hard disk, USB, etc.

What should I do to get the grub menu?

P.S. - I know I have installed Ubuntu correctly, as when I press f11 on starting the PC, a boot menu comes which shows Ubuntu and when I click on it, Ubuntu loads without any problem. My only problem is getting the grub menu

Comment: Did you install both in UEFI boot mode? Or both in the now old (very old) BIOS/MBR configuration. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible so once you start booting in one mode, you cannot change or grub only boots other systems in same boot mode. If `sudo update-grub` does not find Windows and then show grub menu, they probably are not installed in same boot mode. Both Windows & Ubuntu install in boot mode that you boot install media. Use ppa, not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: There will be gazillion ways to fail, and to discuss/cover each case, we have to write a book here, so I posted a link to my "book" instead. Apparently somebody is not too happy with it, without even trying to look at my "book" first, because even the TOC is several pages long. Thanks to that downvote, the answer[/](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128046/843820)link is gone, as s/he wished.